React Native Fetch() Network Request Failed
When I create a brand new project using expo (RN version 0.76.5) and run code Fetch() to consume openIA API to generate a text response, it throws a Network Request Failed. When I try to make a call to the openIA API I don't get any response, just the error Network Request Failed. Here is the fetch I'm sending:
await fetch("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_API_KEY}`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        model: "gpt-4o-mini",
        prompt: prompt,
        temperature: 0.7
      })
    }).then(response => response.json()).then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error('Error making request:', error.message, error.stack);
    });
  }


In other topics it was recommended to add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> and android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in the AndroidManifest.xml file to solve the problem, however, it is still not working.
